# Possible problems with "rooting" page

Tags: bug

The [rooting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting) page says:
"*Before asking how to root your device, please read the full tag wiki …*".

Shouldn't "*full tag wiki*" be a link to the page?
(Otherwise, how would one know how to read it?)

---

Also, ([that page itself](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info)) says:
"*create a new question, and link it to the index*".

Shouldn't that be "*… link it **from** the index*"?

Comment: 1) there are no links possible in the summary IIRC. Unfortunately, a couple of years ago a site change removed the "tag wiki" link the tag referenced; you now have to visit the tag page and follow the "learn more" link there. 2) oops yes, that should be "link to it from the index" – be welcome to edit and earn some points!

Comment: 1) Perhaps the summary could mention the "learn more" link then.
2) Done.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! As for the excerpt: trouble is the "learn more" link is only visible if you're on the tag page, but the excerpt is also shown when hovering the tag where it's applied to a question. In the latter place, rephrasing it such would cause even more confusion, It's very unfortunate SE decided to remove the link from the popup…